# Button is placed under a div instead of to the left of it with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have something like this:

```
  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
   <div id="total">$50,20</div>
   <button class="btn btn-theme" data-role="button" id="purchase"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>Send</button>
                        </div>
```

I want the total to be to the left of the button, but it appears over the button. I already tried making the column bigger but it stays there so the problem is not on the size.

Comment: Literally behind the button? That would make it hidden isn't it?

Comment: Why do you want to put it behind? Do you need to hide it?

Comment: @Swellar Not literally behind, as in z-index, but this: $price [Button] .

Comment: @OblivionCoder I mean to the left

Comment: A visual of your expected result would be better

Comment: `button` has a default display value of `block` - need to use css to do `display: inline` to get it inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want it on the left? like this?

[image]

then,

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
         <label id="total">$50,20</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <button class="btn btn-theme" data-role="button" id="purchase"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i would do it like this

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
<div class=" col-sm-6" id="total">$50,20</div>
<div class=" col-sm-6">
    <button class="btn btn-theme" data-role="button" id="purchase"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>Send</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

div is by default a block element and that means that it takes up the whole available space. 
Try to add this css rules:

```
#total {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Alternatively, you could make the amount a span element like

```
<span id="total">$50,20</span>
```